# Using the consolidate function in VBA to sum data

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the consolidate functionality to sum a number of sheets (with the names apples and oranges), with the same template into one master template.

`ConsolidateRange` is the tab names and the ranges to use in the consolidation.

`Master` is the name of the sheet that I am trying to output the sum to.

Here is my code:

```
ConsolidateRange = "apples!R1C1:R37C6, oranges!R1C1:R37C6"
    
    Worksheets("Master").Range("A1").Consolidate _
    Sources:=Array(ConsolidateRange), _
    Function:=xlSum
```

The error that I'm getting is 'Cannot open consolidation source file 'apples'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to declare a `Variant` and fill it with `Array()` function

```
Dim ConsolidateRangeArray As Variant

ConsolidateRangeArray = Array("apples!R1C1:R37C6", "oranges!R1C1:R37C6")

Worksheets("Master").Range("A1").Consolidate _
Sources:=ConsolidateRangeArray, _
Function:=xlSum
```

or use `Split()` to make a `String` array out of a string with substrings separated by a delimiter

```
Dim ConsolidateRange As String

ConsolidateRange = "apples!R1C1:R37C6,oranges!R1C1:R37C6"

Worksheets("Master").Range("A1").Consolidate _
Sources:=Split(ConsolidateRange, ","), _
Function:=xlSum
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try I still getting the Cannot open consolidation source file 'apples' error

Comment: are those worksheets both in the same, active, workbook?

Comment: Hi, apples and oranges are tabs in the active workbook

Comment: both my codes (as you see them in their last edit) work with sheets named after "Master", "apples" and "oranges". So double check your code for every single statement remembering that all commas and spaces must be where you see them and must not be where you don't see them

Comment: Thanks my bad the file name was ' apples' (with a space at the front and not 'apples', works great thanks!